# Can Servlets and JSP be deployed in OperaUnite?

Tags: jsp, servlets, opera

I have used opera unite for deploying a static html/css/javascript website just for fun. I liked it because even though i don't have my own IP address (As i purchase net connection from an ISP...mebbe they use a NAT box...)Still it works awwsumm...without any problem.

Please explain me how it works..

Also tell me whether i can do server side scripting on it to make it dynamic? I have just learned servlets and JSP and used Apache-Tomcat in the learning process

Answer (score 1, accepted):

sure you can do a dynamic site with Opera Unite! The programming language is just JavaScript - see this link for a "getting started" tutorial:
http://dev.opera.com/articles/view/opera-unite-developer-primer-revisited/#application

and for other articles covering Opera Unite development try
http://dev.opera.com/articles/unite/